# NuGet.Core: This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and no longer maintained

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I upgraded my C# project from .Net 4.6.2 to 4.8. I also took the time to update all my NuGet packages.

There is one package, NuGet.Core, which I believe Microsoft installed. This package now has a warning:

NuGet.Core
Installed: 2.14.0 / Version: 2.14.0 (Deprecated)
This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and no longer maintained.

If I attempt to uninstall the package, I see that other Microsoft packages depend on it, which makes sense ans the Description for this package states: `NuGet.Core is the core framework assembly for NuGet that the rest of NuGet builds upon.`

So what does Microsoft want from me? I cannot uninstall the package, nor do I get a directive as to what to uninstall that replaces it.

I did a Google search and nothing comes up. I guess the problem is still to new.

Environment

- Visual Studio 16.3.1 (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019)
- Target framework: .Net Framework 4.8

**Update:**

My project is a C# WinForms project.

I have 59 or so NuGet packages. Most of the packages appear to be Microsoft in origin. I installed a few of them, true.

> Error Unable to uninstall 'NuGet.Core.2.14.0' because 'Signature.Core.1.0.1' depends on it.

**Contents of package.config:**

```
<package id="AlphaFS" version="2.2.6" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="AlphaVSS" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Auth0.OidcClient.Core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Auth0.OidcClient.WinForms" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.5" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.9.2" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="IdentityModel" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="IdentityModel.OidcClient" version="2.9.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Xdt" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Mono.Cecil" version="0.11.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.17" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="NuGet.Core" version="2.14.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="ObjectListView.Official" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Signature.Core" version="1.0.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="SSH.NET" version="2016.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="StrongNamer" version="0.0.8" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.111.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.111.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.111.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.111.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

My guess is that Visual Studio 20XX installed a lot of them, when I selected the WinForms project. Another option is adding controls, whatever the situation most of the items are the .Net Framework.

Okay, more information.

Signature.Core
Core functions to allow signing a Nuget package after building.

It is possible that I added this package years ago now that I think about it to allow for signing. I might have run into a signed package on installation. Too much time elapsed since I first created this project. I can remove Signature.Core and see if that depends on something further up the food chain.

Thoughts?

Comment: Packages don't get installed by themselves. They're installed through a template, directly by the programmer or as a dependency of another package.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any template that uses `NuGet.Core`, are you using a third party template, perhaps a CMS?

Comment: As for that package itself, what type of project are we talking about? The package itself is 3 years old so the project is probably old too. If you check the [Github dependencies section in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) you'll see the projects that depend on it, eg Kudu, ASP.NET MVC 5 etc. Are you using one of those projects? Perhaps Kudu?

Comment: @DavidG the Github dependencies section shows a few projects, although most of them don't use it at runtime. Perhaps Kudu? ScriptCS? Something that needs to restore packages at runtime ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd be surprised if Kudu is being used (though it is a great project and powers Azure deployments), perhaps BlogEngine.NET though...

Comment: _" Additional Details

NuGet.Core is part of NuGet client v2 APIs. They have been replaced by NuGet client v3 and later APIs."_ as per the nuget page. Maybe a google in that direction sheds some light?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question to address your comment.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger Winforms projects predate NuGet. `NuGet.Core` is explicitly listed in that project file which means *someone* added it, either directly or indirectly through another package

Comment: @DavidG I updated my question to address your query. The direct answer is `Signatuer.Core.1.0.1`.

Comment: `Signature.Core` is another 4-year-old package, I suggest you need to re-evaluate your project requirements here. Do you really need to update the version of .NET Framework? And if you do, you need to check compatibility problems.

Comment: @DavidG I removed `Signature.Core` and then `NuGet.Core`. The install went uneventfully. Nothing bad appears to have happened. I will know more after I fix my current `Auth0`, quite annoying that that `System.TypeLibException`, must be 4.8 issue. Anyways, I will see after I run, then create a setup executable, and install that what bad things, if any, happen. Maybe that 4-year old package did not do anything. Hmm. Interesting.

Comment: Well it seems to be used for signing Nuget packages, if you're not making any Nuget packages, then it should be fine to remove I would guess.

Answer (score 2):

> NuGet.Core: This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and no
>   longer maintained

When the author of one package will no longer maintain the package, he can [deprecate it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/deprecate-packages#deprecation-workflow). As for `Nuget.Core` package, it's once part of NuGet client v2 APIs. Now they have been replaced by NuGet client v3 and later APIs. See additional details [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/).

According to your details, you should use `Signature.Core` package for signing several years ago, since this package depends on these three packages:

[image]

When we try to install the `Signature.Core` package, `package manager` will install these three packages first if they do not exist in current project. So maybe the reason why you have `Nuget.Core` installed is because you installed the `Signature.Core` package, whose author is **Maarten Balliauw**.

> Error Unable to uninstall 'NuGet.Core.2.14.0' because
>   'Signature.Core.1.0.1' depends on it.

In this situation, it's **expected behavior** that you get this message. Cause the `Signature.Core` is installed, and it depends on `Nuget.Core` package. Apart from Nuget.Core package, you'll get similar message when you try to uninstall `Mono.Cecli` before uninstalling the `Signature.Core` like:

[image]

So if you don't need the `Signature.Core` package any more, you can feel free to uninstall it,as well as those three packages(Nuget.Core,Mono.Cecil,Microsoft.Web.Xdt), just take care if other packages depend on them.